# How to add two values in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

This is a simple dropdown with values. I'm trying to pull the values as currency then add.

The values aren't being added (`1+1=2` or `1+2=3`) but instead are concatenating (`1+1=11` or `1+2=12`). Where am I going wrong here?:

```
<script>
    function displayResult()
    {
        var strm=document.getElementById("matt").options[document.getElementById("matt").selectedIndex];
        var t=strm.text.search("\\\$");
        var strb=document.getElementById("box").options[document.getElementById("box").selectedIndex];
        var b=strb.text.search("\\\$");
        var x=strm.text.substr(t+1);
        var y=strb.text.substr(b+1);
        var math= x + y;

        alert(strm.text.substr(t+1));
        alert(strb.text.substr(b+1));
        alert(math);
    }
</script>

<form>
    Select #1:
    <select id="matt">
        <option>$1.00</option>
        <option>$2.00</option>
    </select>

    <br />
    Select #2:
    <select id="box">
        <option>$3.00</option>
        <option>$4.00</option>
    </select>

</form>

<button type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Display index</button>
```

Comment: `math` is probably not a good variable name. but then again, neither are `strm`, `t`, `strb`, `b`, `x`, or `y`... are you a minifier?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `parseInt()` to cast your strings as integers.

```
var math= parseInt(x,10) + parseInt(y,10);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: You can also use ~~x and ~~y instead of parseInt(x,10) and parseInt(y,10). Although ~~ is not as clear as parseInt() for most.

Answer (score 3):

To make sure your values are added as numbers, cast them to `Number` first:

```
Number('2') + Number('2') = 4
'2' + '2' = '22'
```

Comment: Alternatively, one can use `+x` to convert to a number.

Comment: Explicitly casting it to `Number` makes the intention clearer, especially if he's a newbie

Answer (score 1):

Try using parseFloat() or parseInt().. Otherwise it won't recognize it as a number..
It will append as a normal string..

```
var math= parseFloat(x) + parseFloat(y);

alert(math)
```

Check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/jQChx/)

Answer (score 0):

The values are being interpreted as strings, you need to convert them to ints with parseInt prior to adding them.

Answer (score 0):

The `substring()` function returns the *substring* of a given string, which is, of course, a string and not an object upon which math can be performed. If you parse those strings into a number, using `parseInt()`, then it will work:

```
var x= parseInt(strm.text.substr(t+1),10);
var y= parseInt(strb.text.substr(b+1),10);
```

Also, you don't need to keep redeclaring `var`, you could instead comma-separated variable declarations:

```
var x = parseInt(strm.text.substr(t+1),10),
    y = parseInt(strb.text.substr(b+1),10);
```

Comment: substr() was used because my real dropdown also has text populated from a database. <option>Product One $1.00</option> Your suggestion does make sence. Is there a better way then my example?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered something interesting today. I was doing the calculator project on theodinproject. I have addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division functions. Subtraction, multiplication, and division works fine without needing to explicitly tell javascript to treat the parameter as a Number.